# Actionscript: working with the audio / video of FLV

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

I'm wondering if what I want to do is even possible with flash.

If I import an FLV video is there any way to remove the audio, put the audio into a byte array, and then re-add the audio to the flv video?

Thanks for any advice on where to start!

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it completely but you can play two instances of your video and silence one while delaying the other if that is what you are trying to achieve.